# DVD Drive Failing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, troubleshooting, dvd, freeze

I have Windows 7 x64 running on an ASUS M50VM.  The DVD drive works completely unreliably if not at all.

When I first got the machine it came with Windows XP and I upgraded it to Windows Vista X64 and the DVD drive worked fine.

When Windows 7 RC2 came out I tried it on a Virtual Machine and I liked it so much that I upgraded the machine to Win7 RC1.  The DVD drive worked fine.

Of course, RC1 started spontaneously rebooting, so when Windows 7 was released I did a clean install of Windows 7.  Just to clarify...by clean install I mean I did a **format** of the **hard drive** and **installed** it from scratch.

Ever since then, the DVD drive mostly doesn't work.  I can sometimes read from disk but that will often hang.  (Please see my description below of **hang** for details).  CD or DVD writes **always** fails with a **hang** (I have done a successful write only one time.)

Here is what I mean by **hang**:

- Explorer Window is unresponsive.
- Any software accessing the DVD drive is unresponsive.
- The DVD tray will not eject.
- Using a paper clip will eject but the disk is usually spinning real hard.
- Attempting to shut down windows will fail.  I have waited as long as ten minutes but the whole OS seems to hang.  I do a hard shutdown.
- Sometimes accessing the DVD (when it does not cause a **hang**) will still fail and the device will actually seem to disappear from the system until I reboot.

A couple of other things.  It is not a hardware failure.  It is the Windows OS.  I know this because I swapped out my DVD drive with a friend with the same model...his machine is fine (he is still running Vista X64) and my machine still fails.

For what it is worth, I swapped out my primary disk with the INTEL 160GB SSD.

**EDIT**

Here is what System Information shows about my DVD drive

```
Drive   D:  
Description CD-ROM Drive  
Media Loaded    No  
Media Type  DVD Writer  
Name    HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-T50N ATA Device  
Manufacturer    (Standard CD-ROM drives)    
Status  OK  
Transfer Rate   -1.00 kbytes/sec  
SCSI Target ID  0  
PNP Device ID   IDE\CDROMHL-DT-ST_DVDRAM_GSA-T50N________________RR04____\5&2B5B7F1D&0&1.0.0  
Driver  c:\windows\system32\drivers\cdrom.sys (6.1.7600.16385, 144.00 KB (147,456 bytes), 7/13/2009 7:19 PM)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: For the record...here is the model mentioned for the dvd drive in Device Manager.

HL-DT-ST-DVDRAM GSA-T20N ATA

Googling that shows problems but none for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer to this question.

The following URL explains the problem and I got my answer from the second to last post.

[DVD Drive Wont Eject and Feezes Computer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprohardware/thread/1a4fc1a6-9adf-49f2-afce-9d4f4c7fc2a1)

[ASUS Firmware Update that fixed it for me](http://support.asus.com/download/download.aspx?product=3&model=Optical%20Disk%20Drive%20Firmware&SLanguage=en-us&os=8)

Seth

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked for a firmware update for the drive? Is it an OEM drive or a retail drive?

Have you tried this troubleshooter tool?
http://support.microsoft.com/gp/cd_dvd_drive_problems

.

Comment: It is an OEM drive.  I have tried the troubleshooter but it finds no problems.

Seth

Comment: What make and model PC did the drive come from? Some OEMs provide firmware upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

After long search I found HL-DT-ST-DVDRAM GSA-T20N firmware for Win7:
http://files.rpc1.org/index.php?act=category&id=1767

I hope it will help, because it's really difficult to find these drivers.